# Implementing custom sytem.diagnostics for a managed application

Tags: c#, .net, trace, system.diagnostics, event-listener

I am facing a difficult problem. I need to implement a custom diagnostics section just like the system.diagnostics in the app.config for a managed application. The scenario is as follows:

I have an XML file which has a list of trace sources and listeners associated with each of the trace sources.And there is other stuff in the XML file which is not related to the tracing.What I need to do is, read the XML file and set up the trace sources and listeners just like .NET does at application start-up. When I do something like:

TraceSource sample = new TraceSource("SampleTraceSource"); the application should be able to set up the trace source "SampleTraceSource" that is in my XML file, rather than pick it up from the app.config. As of now, .NET does all this behind the scenes so you needn't worry about how it is implemented. I believe this is done in System.dll when the application starts.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be a little vague but I'll attempt to help with a couple key areas.

You can find many examples on the net for reading the XML file.  My personal preference is to use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class and children thereof such as XmlNode, XmlElement, etc.  Alternatively you can look to use the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx).  Both approaches have plenty of resources available.

The loading of trace sources will be handled using members of the [System.Reflection Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx).  Have a look at that namespace, probably at methods such as [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx), and then perhaps come back here with some more specific questions if you get stuck?

Hope that helps.